# Array reduce method + promises

Tags: javascript, arrays, es6-promise, reduce

I have a function that takes data from the current path to create an array ([x, y, z, a, b]) which is then being passed to the reduce method to return a new array of objects. I want to pass in each value from the initial array into a function which returns an object, and add that object to the new array. However after it ends and I console.log accumulate there is nothing being printed, how do I go about using promises in order to fully display the results of accumulate?

```
let accumulate = path.search
      .substring(1)
      .split("+")
      .reduce((acc, val) => {
        FetchMovie(val).then((res) => {
          acc.push(res);
        });
        return acc;
      }, []);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method you pass to `.then()` is executed asynchronously,  so `acc` doesn't get populated until after your reduce operation is complete (which is too late). You can use `Promise.all()`, by firslty mapping (`.map()`) all your values to the Promise returned by your `FetchMovie` function instead:

```
const accumulatedPromise = Promise.all(path.search
  .substring(1)
  .split("+").map(val => FetchMovie(val))
);

accumulatedPromise
  .then(results => console.log(results))
  .catch(err => console.error(err));
```

Comment: My comment is gone.  Anyway, maybe a misunderstanding.  By first block I meant the code inside the promise.  The .then() won't run until that's done.

Comment: @ironarm No worries, yep agreed with that (removed my comments now also). The `.then()` will only run once the promise has resolved, but above I'm saying that it won't run before all the `.reduce()` iterations are finished, which is causing OPs issue.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot use promises in a reducer, unless you resolve all the promises first. A simple way would be to split the string, return the new Promise, and then wait for all the promises to complete.

Here is an example:

```js
const lst = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]; // results after your `split`

Promise.all(
  // replacing `reduce` for `map`
  lst.map(val => FetchMovie(val))
).then(
  // log the new array
  newArray => console.log(newArray)
)
```